# Tool for sketching / drawing / painting quickly (Linux / Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drawing, graphic-design

I'm looking for a simple, fast and intuitive tool for sketching/drawing/painting in Ubuntu/Linux.

I have Gimp installed and I like it, but I'm looking for something simpler and faster, to quickly draw/paint ideas etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Krita**. [**Krita**](https://krita.org/) is a free sketching and painting program. It was designed for concept art, illustrations, and texture painting. You can see what features are Krita supports [here](https://krita.org/en/features/). Krita is an open source software. It's available on Linux. You can check it out [here](https://krita.org/en/download/krita-desktop/).

Answer (score 3):

[Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/) is like PaintDotNet but is open source and multi platform. It is a simple image editor with a simpler interface than gimp. I think you can run `sudo apt-get install pinta`. Otherwise there's PPAs on the site or you can build from [source](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta).

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is a vector drawing package which I find useful for quick drawings and diagrams. It is in the repos and I believe it can easily be installed with `sudo apt-get install inkscape` (I'm on Debian, but the install command should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I recommend [KolourPaint](http://kolourpaint.sourceforge.net/). It's an MS Paint clone (i.e., as prior to Windows 7) from KDE, but unlike other MS Paint clones (I have tried them all) it is actually as intuitive and quick as the original. Its user interface is a lot less menu-y than Pinta, and it loads far faster than GIMP, Krita, or Inkscape.

It doesn't support layering but for quick and dirty stuff I don't find this to be much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

mypaint http://mypaint.org/

azpainter http://azsky2.html.xdomain.jp/

Like a sai: very fast and simple.

Comment: Welcome to our community!  Can you add any more info, and perhaps some screenshots, to help improve your answer?